# Pre-compiled regex with special characters matching

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match if a word such as `*FOO` (* as a normal character) is in a line. My input is a C++ source code. I need to use a pre-compiled regex for this due to program flow requirements, so I tried the following:

```
$pattern = qr/[^a-zA-Z](\*FOO)[^a-zA-Z]|^\s*(\*FOO)[^a-zA-Z]/;
```

And I use it like this:

```
if ($line =~ m/$pattern/) { ... }
```

It works and catches lines containing `*FOO` such as `hey *FOO.BAR` but also matches lines such as:

```
//FOO programming using stuff and things
```

which I want to ignore. What am I missing? Is `\*` not the right way to escape `*` in a pre-compiled regex in perl? If `*FOO` is stored in `$word` and the pattern looks like this:

```
$pattern = qr/[^a-zA-Z](\\$word)[^a-zA-Z]|^\s*(\\$word)[^a-zA-Z]/;
```

Is that different from the previous pattern? Because I tried both and the result seems to be the same.

I found a way to bypass this problem by removing the first char of `$word` and escaping `*` in the pattern, but if `$word = "**.?FOO"` for example, how do I create a `qr//` with `$word` so that all the meta-characters are escaped?

Comment: you only need a single backslash.

Comment: I edited my question, it is only a single backslash in the first. my bad.

Comment: Also you probably want to look into `\b` and/or non-capturing groups `(?:whatever)` which would allow you to group alternatives.

Comment: I found a way to bypass this problem by removing the first char of `$word` and escaping `*` in the pattern, but if `$word = "**.?FOO"` for example, how do I create a `qr//` with `$word` so that all the meta-characters are escaped?

Comment: You can use `\Q` and `\E` to escape metacharacters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to escape the `*`. One way to do it is by the [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) `\Q` operator:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $qr = qr/\Q*FOO/;

while (<DATA>) { print if /$qr/ }

__DATA__
//FOO programming using stuff and things
hey *FOO.BAR
```

Note that this escapes all ASCII non-"word" characters through the rest of the pattern. If you need to limit its action to only a part of the pattern then stop it using `\E`.  Please see linked docs.

The above determines whether `*FOO` is in the line, regardless of whether it is a word or a part of one. It is not clear to me which is needed.  Once that is specified the pattern can be adjusted.

Note that `/\*FOO/` works, too. What you tried failed probably because of all the rest that you are trying to match, which purpose I do not understand.  If you only need to detect whether the pattern is present the above does it. if there is a more specific requirement please clarify.

---

As for the examples: for me that string `//FOO...` is *not matched* by the main (first) `$pattern` you show.  The second one won't interpolate `$word` -- but is firstly much too convoluted.  The regex can really tie one in nasty knots when pushed; I suggest to keep it simple as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

#### Question 1:

```
my $word = '*FOO';
my $pattern = qr/\\$word/;
```

is equivalent to

```
my $pattern = qr/\\*FOO/; # zero or more '\' followed by 'FOO'
```

The `$word` is simply interpolated as is.

To get something equivalent to

```
my $pattern = qr/\*FOO/;
```

you should use

```
my $word = '*FOO';
my $pattern = qr/\Q$word\E/;
```

By default, an interpolated variable is considered a mini-regular expression, meta characters in the variable such as `*`, `+`, `?` are still interpreted as meta character. `\Q...\E` will add a backslash before any character not matching `/[A-Za-z_0-9]/`, thus any meta characters in the interpolated variable is interpreted as literal ones. Refer to [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

#### Question 2

I tried

```
my $pattern = qr/[^a-zA-Z](\*FOO)[^a-zA-Z]|^\s*(\*FOO)[^a-zA-Z]/;
my $line = '//FOO programming using stuff and things';

if($line =~ m/$pattern/){
    print "$&\n";
}
else{
    print "No match!";
}
```

and it printed "No match!". I can't explain how you get it matched.